# Is there a way to restrict access to paid subscriptions shared to my Family Group for specific members using Family Link?

Tags: google-family-link, google-one

I am the manager of a Google Family Group of 4 members.

I have separate paid subscriptions to Google One and YouTube Premium.

I want to share both subscriptions with my Family Group but control which members have access to each subscription.

For example, give one member access to YouTube Premium, but not the Google One storage, while the other 3 members have access to both subscriptions.

Is there a way to use Family Link to control access individually for each member of my Google Family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Family Link is a service that allows parents to enforce **parental controls** on their children's devices. Restricting content, approving certain apps, controlling screen time, etc.

Family Link may assist in protecting your minors, but it will not manage your subscriptions.  It can't manage services shared within your **Family Group**.  If you share a premium product with the Family Group, it is shared to all **Family Group** members.

This unfettered sharing is, of course, subject to any content restrictions that might be enforced via **Family Link**.  For example, if a minor has controls imposed on a device via their Google account, those controls would apply to YouTube Premium the same way they would to the free version.

If you want more fine-grained control over your family's accounts, consider a paid Google Workspace account which is intended for businesses that need more granular user permissions.